# TableLayout row strech/shrink

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to fit a 20x20 table into a view using a programmatically built `TableLayout`.  The `setStretchAllColumns`/`setShrinkAllColumns` methods work perfectly for squeezing all the columns in, but I haven't found a way to get all the rows in.

Is there a corresponding method for packing the rows in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any `setStretchAllColumns/setShrinkAllColumns` for rows in a `TableLayout`. One thing that you could try(I haven't tested it) is to give your `TableLayout` a `weigtSum` of `20`(with the method `setWeightSum()`) and then set the `weight`(the `layout_weight` attribute from a xml layout) of `1` for each of your 20 `TableRow`s in the `TableLayout`.

Comment: does it work? I assume if u don't specify any weight for row and sumWeight of table that weight for all elements is equal.. 
wrong assumption?

Comment: @Ewoks Not all elements will fit the screen. You are free to test it.

Comment: I have an issue making row heights fit the table.. Adding padding up/down is current workaround but don't like it at all cause I need to set separate padding for different screens... setting weights didn't work either..so you are welcomed to propose more ideas if u came up with something.. 10q ;)

Comment: @Ewoks The code from my answer(with only a `TableLayout` + `TableRows`) worked as I used it in a simple project. It may not work in a layout with other elements beside the `TableLayout`. You should post a question with your exact layout and what doesn't work.

Comment: thanks.. I reviewed it and make it work for me thanks to your guidance ;) Cheers