# Rotate Screen TableLayout

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout Small buttons and matrix 8 of 8 are described in XML, when i turn the display , buttons do not see, how i can describe that for all types of screens, and the state retained all the elements were visible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Table8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button22"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button23"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button24"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button25"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button26"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button27"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button28"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button29"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button31"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button30"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button32"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button33"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button34"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button35"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button36"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button37"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button38"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button39"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button40"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button41"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button42"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button43"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button44"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button45"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button46"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button47"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button48"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button49"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button50"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button51"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button52"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button53"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button54"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button55"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button56"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button57"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button58"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button59"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button60"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button61"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button62"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button63"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button64"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>





    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Are you describing the layout using a layout file? If so, can you share it?

Comment: add `android:configChanges="orientation"` under `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @Ramin Post your question clearly with some layout xml code.

Answer (score 1):

i would do it in `Manifest.xml` at the `activity` like this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Okay I think your buttons are out of the display. Try this, go to your layout and switch to Graphical Layout, there you should see your layout. Switch form Portrait to Landscape. And now you can create a onw landscape layout in the right corner on top.

Answer (score 0):

can try Weight sum as in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952895/tablelayout-row-strech-shrink)

or

Put the Table layout in the scroll view in you want same layout...

Comment: Yes, I'll deal with the weight now

Comment: and also see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns